# Python3.4 : PySpark / SparklingPandas / Spark

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.x, apache-spark

I currently have a pandas DataFrame but in hearing about spark technology I would like to work with pyspark or sparklingpandas.  I am not sure which python spark version to download for use with python 3.4, nor do I understand how to install it on ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 0):

you need not to , just download spark prebuilt versions
https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

> Once you download the zip , unpack it and just bin/pyspark and it will
>   open the interactive shell for you to play with-

For more details about basic -
https://spark.apache.org/screencasts/1-first-steps-with-spark.html

For basic operation , even if you download hadoop prebuilt version , you don't need that , but further operation will.
You can as well try building spark using maven

Go the above link , select the following settings and click download shown in the red marked link

[image]

Apache Spark 1.4 supports Python 3
http://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-1-4-0.html

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4897

Comment: I'm guessing I downloaded the wrong thing... I am returning, "You need to build Spark before running this program"

Comment: I  have updated what you can download to try as an image

Comment: and how would you run with python3.4 instead of 2.7?

Comment: does it stop you to launch the shell using Python 3.4

Comment: Apache Spark 1.4 does support python 3

Comment: I'm just not sure how to run python3.4 with spark... for instance I run `./pyspark` and the default is to open python2.7

Comment: well once you click pyspark does it open the shell or not , it must you need not to set the version of your python in your config, unless its not in your home

Comment: it opens the shell yes... but with python 2.7

Comment: well my python version is 2.7.8 so i can't test that but if your pyspark takes python 2.7 , it does mean your environment variable is still pointing to 2.7 version python

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80882/discussion-between-abc-and-aran-freel).